# Selecting LOB using Database Link (OCI) in Postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I have a database link set up to connect to an Oracle 11gR2 database from a Postgres 9.1 server.  This uses OCI for the connection.

However, when I try to select any CLOB data I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: OCI error: ORA-01406: fetched column value was truncated
```

Is there anything that can be changed in the OCI to allow this to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I am noticing that a lot of db's have trouble connecting to text fields in PostgreSQL.  Is there a reason it has to be CLOB?  Can you wrap in a function that would read the whole field?

My guess is that Oracle uses a streaming interface for CLOBs similar to the LOB postgresql interface but without the escaping.  As a result PostgreSQL isnt really sure what to do with the value when it comes over.